# DllNotFoundException while trying to "fix" LuaInterface, but why?

Tags: c#, mono, lua, luainterface

Since my game, which I'd really like to be Mono-usable, does not seem to run under Linux because LuaInterface is being a jerk (see the [the relevant SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533799) for more on that), I've decided to do what's suggested there. I wrote my own Lua511.LuaDLL class to reflect the one used by LuaInterface, replacing every single public function with its respective DllImport from lua51:

```
//For example, like this:
[DllImport("lua51")]
public static extern IntPtr luaL_newstate();
```

With the edited LuaInterface.dll (which now hosts its own Lua511.LuaDLL) *and* a pure, native Win32 lua51.dll in my game's startup folder, I somehow get a DllNotFoundException when LuaInterface tries initialize:

```
public Lua()
{
   luaState = LuaDLL.luaL_newstate(); //right there, right then.
   ...
```

Ofcourse, with the DLL right there it shouldn't do that, right? Strangely, putting back the messed-up .Net version of lua51.dll gives an EntryPointNotFoundException instead. The mind boggles.

So what's up with that?

Relevant source code: [Lua511.cs](http://helmet.kafuka.org/Lua511.cs), dropped it in the LuaInterface project, then removed the reference so it'd be replaced.

Edit: Screw this, I'm gonna look for alternatives. Or roll my own. Or just stop caring about Linux compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You referenced [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1533799). I took the other way to solve the problem and started to develop a new Lua .NET interface. I called it Lua4Net.

You can find the [sources on Google hosting](http://parallel-tasks-simulator.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Src/Lua4Net/). And [here the unit tests](http://parallel-tasks-simulator.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Src/Lua4Net.Tests/).

Currently implemented features: Execute code with exception handling and provide the return values; register global functions with parameter handling.

Features that will follow: Get/set global variables; debugging support, ...

You can find the used [native windows DLL here](http://parallel-tasks-simulator.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Lib/Lua/) (it is the renamed VC++ 9.0 DLL from [here](http://luaforge.net/frs/?group_id=110)).

AND: Today I ran my first *Linux/Mono tests*, and all my unit tests worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK mono uses [.so extension](http://mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries) for native libraries under Linux by default.

Try to rename your lua51.dll to lua51.so or change dllname in DllImport attribute. Or use dllmap.

Comment: Eeeeeh no. I'm running this under Windows, actually. And the DllImport does not specify an extension.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've misunderstood.

I've examined lua51.dll from LuaInterface with Dependency Walker and found that it exports *no* functions. 

Then I've rebuilt lua51 from sources. It started to load and then failed with EntryPointNotFoundException for function (both on .NET and Mono). This is normal since there's no such function - this is a macro in lua.h defined on top of lua_createtable. The same is for many others 'functions'  in lua.h. 

So, I think you should replace dll imports for them with calls to real functions and you've had a chance to make LuaInterface working.

Comment: I've edited your file lua511.cs to run simple scripts. see here http://pastie.org/659584. Hope this will help