# LuaInterface and 64Bit

Tags: c#, windows, lua, luainterface

Ok i'm currently using LuaScript v5.1 in a Game engine i'm using. and the handy LuaInterface that comes along with it. i've tested it on a range of systems running a range of OS's.
LuaInterface seems to fail on 64bit Operating Systems.
Could anyone point me to a 64bit Compiled LuaInterface.dll, or is there any alternative to the LuaInterface that can be used, because LuaInterface is extremely useful and i dont think i would be able to write a more extensive interface by myself using lua51. (I'm not that good, sadly)

Any help or links would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks alot guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the [LuaInterface](http://code.google.com/p/luainterface/) source code from the [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) [repository](http://luainterface.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/) hosted on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/). It contains Visual Studio project files for building it yourself. Welcome to the world of open-source software!

Comment: I've just linked a local repo to the online repo and am updating as we speak.
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I just found some links that might help with your problem.

This shows how to modify compiled assemblies to force them to run 32 bit:

http://bchavez.bitarmory.com/archive/2008/04/29/badimageformatexception-errors.aspx

This shows how to compile to target 32 bit:

http://www.atalasoft.com/kb/article.aspx?id=10165

Read this article for a good understanding of 32 and 64 bit managed apps:

http://blogs.msdn.com/joshwil/archive/2004/03/11/88280.aspx

Another good link that talks about 32 vs 64 bit:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasics32bitAnd64bitConfusionAroundX86AndX64AndTheNETFrameworkAndCLR.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use **KopiLuaInterface**. I uses KopiLua, which is written entirely in C# and provides all the well-known interfaces like LuaInterfaces. It even implements the same namespaces as LuaInterface, so you don't have to change anything except your references!

I just migrated my project from LuaInterface to KopiLuaInterface in under 10 minutes without changing a single line of code!

You can find KopiLuaInterface here: https://github.com/gfoot/kopiluainterface/releases

Just remove your LuaInterface and lua51 DLL files from your project and add the 3 DLLs from the KopiLuaInterface release, update your references and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

NLua supports 64 bits and is available via NuGet.

NLua site : http://nlua.org

GitHub: https://github.com/nlua/nlua

NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLua/